# re.findall() not returning all matches

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

```
      import re
      text = 'fruits to be sold are apple orange and peach'
      x = re.findall(r'fruits.*(apple|orange|peach).*',text,re.I)
      print(x)
```

The objective of the code is to return a list, containing names of the fruits in the sentence after the word 'fruits'.

so the expected result should be like

```
['apple','orange','peach']
```

but instead am getting only the last match in the sentence.i.e peach.
Could someone help me out where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Did you try tweaking your pattern at an online regex tester? like https://regex101.com/?

Comment: Your expression contains "fruits". The string contains "fruits" only once. So how could there be more than one match?

Comment: Your pattern will match 'fruits' followed by one of the alternatives, it only _searches_ the string once. Maybe do it in two steps: capture r'fruits.*', then _findall_ on the result.

Comment: I got your point but what should have to do to get all fruit names after that 'fruits'  string

Comment: Thanks guys! got it working

Comment: Pythex is also a great online regex builder for python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your regexp by the simpler

```
x = re.findall(r'(apple|orange|peach)',text,re.I)
```

Comment: but I want to capture after the word  'fruits'

Comment: `findall` gives non-overlapping matches, so you can't use that one directly for that. Perhaps what you are looking for is something like `re.findall('(apple|orange|peach)', re.match(r'fruits(.*)', text).group(1))`?